# iterate a number of dictionary items

Tags: c#, dictionary, ienumerable

I have the following Dictionary:

```
 Dictionary<string, List<string>> myList = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>();
```

This dictionary gets populated, I'm never going to know how many items I will have.

An example of the output:
Elements of Dictionary: (Key,Value)

```
 {"Code",{"Test1", "Test2", "Test3"}}

 {"Desc",{"Desc1", "Desc2", "Desc3"}}

 {"Name",{"name1", "name2", "name3"}}
```

How can I loop through every dictionary and get the value i.e. by index

something that would yield  ->

```
{Code = "Test1", Desc = "desc", Name = "name1"}
{Code = "Test2", Desc = "desc2", Name = "name2"}
{Code = "Test3", Desc = "desc3", Name = "name3"}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: How do you map corresponded name and item ?

Comment: Why use a Tuple? What is the use of the first parameter if it always duplicate the value from the dictionary?

Comment: I have a class that it corresponds too. The tuple was something I was trying I had a list of strings before. This can be changed.

Comment: Why not create strongly typed objects and forgo all the pain of mapping?

Comment: @ErikPhilips because that is exactly what the goal of parsing this dictionary is, ending up with strongly typed objects. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to build a set of arrays for each column of your data instead of for each rows like the Dictionary enumerator will provide you. This can be achieved through the use of the Aggregate extension method and a simple Select statement.

```
// Assuming the following class as a destination type
class Foo
{
    public Foo(string[] values)
    {
        Code = values[0];
        Name = values[1];
        Desc = values[2];
    }

    public string Code;
    public string Name;
    public string Desc;
}

// This would be the code required to parse the data
var destination = dataSource["Code"].Aggregate(new List<Foo>(), (entries, _) => 
{
    var curentRow = entries.Count();

    var entryData = dataSource.Select(property => property.Value[curentRow]).ToArray();

    entries.Add(new Foo(entryData));

    return entries;
});
```

In this case, we use the `Code` property as a key to figure out how many entries there are in your data source (your dictionary). If there are rows in your dictionary with missing values (less items than in the Code row), this code will fail as it assumes that there are the same amount of items in all the rows.

The `Aggregate` method acts like a for loop in this case, providing us with a basic counter named `currentRow` that we will use later to access specific entries in your data. This counter is the amount of entries we stored into the `List<Foo>`. It starts at 0 and it increments each time we add a new value to the result set.

The next step is to look at all the entries in your data source and to access the value that matches the current row. We then convert it into an array and feeds it into the constructor of your destination type that knows how to deserialize this data.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic solution which perfectly solves your problem. I have created an IEnumerable object so that you can increment foreach loop by "Code","Desc",... .

Once you get the strings( which are Keys of Dictionary ) you can interate through the list that is the value of each key in the dictionary. The code below Writes and counts all elements in Dictionary and for each Values writes all elements in Lists.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static IEnumerable<string> Helper() // Neccessary to use in foreach loop
        {
            yield return "Code";
            yield return "Desc";
            yield break;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, List<string>> container = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            List<string> l1 = new List<string>();
            List<string> l2 = new List<string>();

            l1.Add("l1s1");
            l1.Add("l1s2");
            l1.Add("l1s3");

            l2.Add("l2s1");
            l2.Add("l2s2");
            l2.Add("l2s3");

            container.Add("Code", l1);
            container.Add("Desc", l2);

            int count = 0;
            foreach (string k in Helper()) // get all Keys
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < container[k].Count; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(container[k][i].ToString()); // Write each element in list
                    count++;
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(count.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need to know how many elements will be in each list.Output is like :

[image]

Or without creating Helper()  you can do like below:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, List<string>> container = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            List<string> l1 = new List<string>();
            List<string> l2 = new List<string>();

            l1.Add("l1s1");
            l1.Add("l1s2");
            l1.Add("l1s3");

            l2.Add("l2s1");
            l2.Add("l2s2");
            l2.Add("l2s3");

            container.Add("Code", l1);
            container.Add("Desc", l2);

            int count = 0;
            foreach (string k in new string [] {"Code","Desc"}) // get all Keys
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < container[k].Count; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(container[k][i].ToString()); // Write each element in list
                    count++;
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(count.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a rather strange use of `yield`. You could simply do `foreach (string k in new [] { "Code", "Desc" })` instead of all that.

Answer (score -1):

looks like the wrong data structure. Seems like you have a set of objects each with an arbitrary set of attributes. You need `map<string,map<string,string>>`

```
"item1"->code:'code1",desc:"desc1"....
"item2"->code:'code2",desc:"desc2", color:"red", size:'42"
```

......