# Group Sequential List By Key

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to group a list of related entries.

My list looks like:

```
new List<string>() { "Entry1", "Metadata1", "Metadata2", 
                       "Entry2", "Metadata3", "Metadata4" };
```

I want to group on "Entry" such that I end up with `{ "Entry1", "Metadata1", "Metadata2" }` and `{ "Entry2", "Metadata3", "Metadata4" }` as the groups.

The number of items between "Entry" fields is indeterminate.  I'd like to accomplish this using LINQ.

How can I group these into collections that are separated by the `Entry` elements?

Comment: How do you see this working - will the items always be in groups of 3, or do you want a new object every time there's a string beginning Entry in the list, with all following items after it?

Comment: @JohnLBevan, the latter.  There will be an unknown number of entries between each set.  Every time it sees an item beginning with "Entry", it should create a new list whose contents are that "Entry" as well as the items that follow leading up to the next "Entry" field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution to this may be getting the indexes of `Entries`, and use `GetRange` method of `List<T>` to get the items in the range using the indexes:

```
var indices = yourList
       .Where(x => x.StartsWith("Entry"))
       .Select(x => yourList.IndexOf(x))
       .ToList();

var groups = indices
     .Select((x,idx) => idx != indices.Count - 1 
                               ? yourList.GetRange(x, indices[idx + 1] - x)
                               : yourList.GetRange(x, yourList.Count - x))
     .ToList();
```

Comment: This works very well also!  This is an interesting approach, and a bit closer to how my brain wanted to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm going to mark this one as correct because it's slightly more generic.  The grouping doesn't care about the type, which is nice, and makes it a little more readily portable.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution and output. Hope this is what you want to do .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> datas = new List<string>() { "Entry1", "Metadata1", "Metadata2", "Entry2", "Metadata3", "Metadata4" };
            List<List<string>> grouped = new List<List<string>>();
            int count = -1;
            foreach (string e in datas)
            {
                if (e.StartsWith("Entry"))
                {
                    grouped.Add(new List<string>());
                    grouped[++count].Add(e);
                }
                else
                {
                    grouped[count].Add(e);
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < grouped.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < grouped[i].Count; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(grouped[i][j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Output is as you wish :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution.  This works, but I was seeking a solution that uses LINQ.  Regardless, yours works as advertised.

Answer (score 2):

What you're after is an `IGrouping<TKey,TValue>`or an `ILookup<TKey,TValue>`. Trouble is, you have to call framework methods to generate them that don't work for this scenario because you can't extract both a key and a value (or a key and multiple values if you use a Dictionary) within each iteration. The problem with using LINQ in this scenario is that in order to get what you want you have to end up iterating over the collection multiple times in order to group everything correctly. The most efficient means to do what you're asking would be to manually go over the data in a for loop and create a `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>`, creating DictionaryEntries and adding them every time you hit a new key. A compromise would be to project the data using ToLookup, adding entries for the keys with a "junk" key that you then go through and filter out like this:

```
var data = new List<string>() { "Key1", "Value1", "Value2", 
                                "Key2", "Value3", "Value4" };
string workingKey = null; 
data.ToLookup(item => {
    if(item.StartsWith("Key"))
    {
        workingKey = item;
        return String.Empty; //use whatever here
    }
    return workingKey;
}).Where(g => g.Key != String.Empty); //make sure to enumerate this if you plan on setting workingKey after this EDIT: Where is enumerating so no need to enumerate again
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea (needs polish), implemented in LINQPad (and here's a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/S0WTGO)):

```
void Main()
{
    var data = new List<string>() { "Entry1", "Metadata1", "Metadata2", 
                                    "Entry2", "Metadata3", "Metadata4" };

    PairWithGroup(data).GroupBy(t=>t.Item1).Dump();
}

private IEnumerable<Tuple<string,string>> PairWithGroup(IEnumerable<string> input) {
    string groupName = null;
    foreach (var entry in input) {
        if (entry.StartsWith("Entry")) {
            groupName = entry;
        }
        yield return Tuple.Create(groupName, entry);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works quite well.  I like the use of `yield` as well, I often struggle to find a place for it in daily use.

Comment: @GrantH. here there is nice example of usage of yield :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27362943/iterate-a-number-of-dictionary-items/27367221#27367221

Answer (score 1):

.Net Fiddle Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/140PwW

**Code:**

```
//create initial list
List<string> myList = new List<string>{"Entry1","a","b","Entry2","c","d","e"};

//remember previous group name
string previousGroupName = null;

//create grouped list
var myGroupedList = 
    myList.Select(i => new{
        Value=i
        ,GroupName=(i.StartsWith("Entry")?(previousGroupName = i):previousGroupName)
    })
    .GroupBy(gb => gb.GroupName);

//output to LinqPad (if running there)
myGroupedList.Dump();
```

**Results:**

```
Key = Entry1 
    Value       GroupName
    Entry1      Entry1 
    a           Entry1 
    b           Entry1 

Key = Entry2 
    Value       GroupName
    Entry2      Entry2 
    c           Entry2 
    d           Entry2 
    e           Entry2
```